# Coverage checks have not been met

Tags: maven, jacoco

I want to generate junit's test coverage report. So I use jacoco maven plugin:

here my pom.xml

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>PACKAGE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.50</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But when I run this:

```
mvn clean verify
```

I get error:

```
Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:report (report) @ mymodule1 ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /home/alexeij/dev/projects/JavaTestMavenBOM/mymodule1/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'mymodule1' with 7 classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mymodule1 ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/alexeij/dev/projects/JavaTestMavenBOM/mymodule1/target/mymodule1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:check (jacoco-check) @ mymodule1 ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /home/alexeij/dev/projects/JavaTestMavenBOM/mymodule1/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'mymodule1' with 7 classes
[WARNING] Rule violated for package com.gmail.alexei28.javatestmavenbom.module1.ngnms: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.50
[WARNING] Rule violated for package com.gmail.alexei28.javatestmavenbom.module1: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.50
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for testprojectbom 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] testprojectbom ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.090 s]
[INFO] mymodule1 .......................................... FAILURE [  1.710 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.961 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-01T12:24:30+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:check (jacoco-check) on project mymodule1: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

Details:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:check (jacoco-check) on project mymodule1: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:check (jacoco-check) on project mymodule1: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details.
    at org.jacoco.maven.CheckMojo.executeCheck (CheckMojo.java:194)
    at org.jacoco.maven.CheckMojo.executeMojo (CheckMojo.java:169)
    at org.jacoco.maven.AbstractJacocoMojo.execute (AbstractJacocoMojo.java:46)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
```

Comment: what is your question? Do you want to know the reason behind or do you want to bypass this coverage?

Answer (score 6):

You output is expected.

The report is generated in folder `target/site/jacoco`. See the Maven Build log below.

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:report (report) @ mymodule1 ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /home/alexeij/dev/projects/JavaTestMavenBOM/mymodule1/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'mymodule1' with 7 classes
```

Check your `target/site/jacoco` folder and it should be similar to below:

```bash
target/site/jacoco/
├── index.html
├── io.sampadadubey.java.jacoco
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.source.html
│   ├── JacocoDemoApplication.html
│   └── JacocoDemoApplication.java.html
├── jacoco.csv
├── jacoco-resources
│   ├── branchfc.gif
│   ├── branchnc.gif
│   ├── branchpc.gif
│   ├── bundle.gif
│   ├── class.gif
│   ├── down.gif
│   ├── greenbar.gif
│   ├── group.gif
│   ├── method.gif
│   ├── package.gif
│   ├── prettify.css
│   ├── prettify.js
│   ├── redbar.gif
│   ├── report.css
│   ├── report.gif
│   ├── session.gif
│   ├── sort.gif
│   ├── sort.js
│   ├── source.gif
│   └── up.gif
├── jacoco-sessions.html
└── jacoco.xml
```

Your build is configured like this:

1. Runs `prepare-agent` goal during `initialize` phase.
2. Runs `report` goal during `test` phase.
3. Runs `check` goal during `verify` phase.

Your build is failing at `verify` phase for failing to conform to configured `check`. Error from the `check` goal is as below:

> `Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details`.

Here are the logs which tell you the failure details.

```bash
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:check (jacoco-check) @ mymodule1 ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /home/alexeij/dev/projects/JavaTestMavenBOM/mymodule1/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'mymodule1' with 7 classes
[WARNING] Rule violated for package com.gmail.alexei28.javatestmavenbom.module1.ngnms: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.50
[WARNING] Rule violated for package com.gmail.alexei28.javatestmavenbom.module1: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.50
```

To make it more easily readable.

```bash
Rule violated for package com.gmail.alexei28.javatestmavenbom.module1.ngnms: lines
covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.50

Rule violated for package com.gmail.alexei28.javatestmavenbom.module1: lines
covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.50
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question is unclear so I'll answer it as if you want to bypass jacoco.
All you have to do is delete the specific code in your pom stated below:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>PACKAGE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.50</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This will simply skip the check or delete it.